# Can you use a 'hidden' button to start something?

Tags: javascript, css, button

I am trying to have images appear on click of a button. I have that process working, but I'd like for the users/players to not see the buttons I will be clicking.

Is there a way to set a space where the button 'still lives' but isn't visible?

I'm pretty sure I'm going to need to get cute and hide the buttons on screen. However, if i can set them to specific spots and have them invisible, but clickable, that would be ideal.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm using HTML, CSS and Java. There's no JQuery in the code (for context)

Comment: What do you mean by "I will be clicking"? Don't the users do the clicking?

Comment: Why do you need a button? Just use a DIV.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question itself is not clear but from what I understand you can do something like that in a various ways:

-- If the case is making them visible before click, you can set their z-index to "-1" and when you need to click them, change it to "1"

-- If the case is buttons are going to stay on the page and clickable but no one can visually see them, you can set their opacity to 0. Even they are invisible you can still click them via this method.
--> To position them on a specific area on your page you can use your CSS as the way you want. No need to worry about opacity change.

Comment: This is EXACTLY the answer I needed. I needed the button to be invisible and functional. Thank you so much for your help. I don't have the 'rep' to upvote you, but this was the solution to my problem.

Comment: Hehehe, glad to hear that m8, just mark this answer as 'approved', so stackoverflow can add it to 'Solved' :)